# What is a recommended approach for building Emacs from the unreleased development sources in a Mac OS X environment?

Tags: macos, emacs, environment

I am sort of switching to a Mac based development environment as the Mac line of laptops and workstations contains some very nice systems, albeit pricey.  As an occasional Emacs developer, I want to build Emacs from the git/bazaar sources.  Much to my surprise, the first time I attempted to do this using Xcode4, I discovered that the version of autoconf supplied with Xcode is less than that required by Emacs.  So this raises the question: what approaches do those who develop Emacs daily using Mac hardware take in order to have the required libraries and headers available to build and run the Emacs development code on OS X?  Left to my own devices, I will fetch and build the versions of components required by Emacs that are not satisfied by Xcode and put those into /usr/local/... but it does occur to me that other approaches, using fink for one example, might be less work and/or more satisfying, hence the question.  This also applies to the add-on packages for graphics support (pdf, dvi, png, etc.) that are not supplied by Xcode.

Comment: If you don't insist on building on your own, you could get along with the nightly builds from http://emacsformacosx.com/builds

Comment: Philipp: I think the intention is to work on Emacs' C code base.

Comment: It looks like the Emacs archive have changed again -- and there is no updated description on how to build under Mac OS X -- so we would need to lift this question once again.

Answer (score 2):

The directions in the file `nextstep/INSTALL` is to issue the following commands:

```
./configure --with-ns
make install
```

The resulting "app" can be found in `nextstep/Emacs.app`.

However, there is an XCode project provided with Emacs, but I haven't got it to work.

Comment: These instructions are now stale.  The development sources now use `autogen` to generate `configure` which failed for me since `autogen` requires `autoconf-2.65` or later and Xcode comes with version 2.61.

Comment: Whoa! You look away for a second, and everything has changed! (The `configure` script seems to have been removed on the 20:th this month, on the Emacs 24 trunk.) Fortunately, it looks as though it works if you run `./autogen/copy_autogen`.

Comment: Indeed -- I raised an Emacs bug report a few days ago because it seems stupid to break the old `./configure && make install` method on ideological grounds: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8342

Answer (score 0):

I use the [macports](http://macports.org) package 'emacs-app', which is just emacs configured `--with-ns`. They're currently at version 23.2.1

Even if you want to build emacs direct from GNU repos, using macports to get autotools should save you some time and energy. The autoconf package is at 2.68, and emacs configure.ac requires 2.65